# Why would both Eclipse and Netbeans both not find workspace on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

When starting my MacBook Pro this morning, Eclipse says:

> Workspace in use or cannot be created, choose a different one

and Netbeans says:

> The Source folder /Volumes/data/domains/... cannot be restored.

I have deleted the .lock file out of my `metadata` directory in the eclipse workspace, and afterwards restarted the computer, but still have the problem:

[image]

In finder I can navigate to the workspaces no problem, those volumes are connected.

I am quite certain I didn't have Eclipse and Netbeans open when I closed the computer as I am aware that it causes these problems.

In `configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` I tried changing the RECENT_WORKSPACES entry but this didn't have any effect.

**How can I get Eclipse and Netbeans to recognize their workspaces again?**

Comment: Have you mounted multiple volumes with the name "data"? What is the output of `ls /Volumes`? Have you tried selecting the workspace when prompted to do so in Eclipse (I have no experience using Netbeans)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that for some reason the volume name was changed from `data` to `data-1`, perhaps because it was offline and automatically renamed it. The solution was to disconnect (pulled cable), disconnect all, reboot, then `data-1` was gone, then pointed Eclipse and Netbeans to `data` again and it worked.